How to improve prediction quality of LSTM model
I am trying to train an LSTM-based model in MATLAB to predict 365 next values given 365 previous values of a time series. Input shape is (1000, 365) and output shape is (1000, 365) i.e. there are 1000 rows where each input row is a time series of 1 year data and each corresponding output row is the prediction for the next year. The values themselves are floating-point numbers. Before feeding to the model, I am standardizing the values using the following formula:
train_stdized = (train_array - mu_train) / sig_train;

where
mu_train = mean of the training data
sig_train = standard deviation of the training data

My model architecture and training options are as follows:
layers = [sequenceInputLayer(lag)
lstmLayer(512)
fullyConnectedLayer(150)
fullyConnectedLayer(future)]; 

training_options = trainingOptions("adam", "Metrics",["rmse"], ...
        InitialLearnRate=0.01,Verbose=true,VerboseFrequency=10, ...
        MaxEpochs=50,MiniBatchSize=1, ...
        ObjectiveMetricName="rmse", ...
        ValidationData={x_val, y_val}, ValidationFrequency=10, ...
        LearnRateSchedule="piecewise", LearnRateDropPeriod=100, LearnRateDropFactor=0.1, ...
        OutputNetwork="best-validation");


The issue is, the predictions' trend does not match the input trend. On the contrary, it's just the opposite - the forecast range is either much higher or much lower than the input data. Perhaps the below graphs will make it clearer:




In the first graph, while the input ranges from 0-1500, the forecast ranges from 0-5800. In the second one, input range is 10-580 while the forecast hovers around 80-120.

I have tried:

increasing the # of epochs to 250
adding a dropout layer with a 20% probability of ignoring the inputs after the lstm layer
using a bi-lstm layer instead of lstm
changing the size of fully connected layer to 480 based on the formula (2/3)*(input_size + output_size) as mentioned here.

However, it hasn't made much difference.

I'd like to know if I can try anything else to improve the predictions so their range reflects that of the input. I'm not very experienced in this area so I apologize if this sounds like a basic question. Appreciate your help.

P.S. I have tried to include everything that I thought relevant. However, if I mistakenly left out any information, please let me know and I will add it.

Welcome to Cross Validated! predict 365 next values given 365 previous values of a time series Is there reason to expect the previous 365 values to be particularly predictive of the next 365?
